# How to direct packets belonging to a TCP connection to a specific lcore in DPDK?

Tags: tcp, rss, dpdk

We want a specific lcore to receive packets belonging to the both sides of a TCP connection. I.e. packets going from client to Server (CtoS) and those which going from Server to Client (StoC), both be directed to a single lcore. It seems that the RSS guarantees the packets belonging to a stream (one way data flow) to be directed to the same lcore. To direct both side of a direction to the same lcore we need a symmetric RSS.

- How we can configure a NIC (e.g. Intel 82599) to direct packets belonging to connection to a specific lcore?
- Is there any way to direct packets belonging to a connection to a specific lcore when the CtoS traffic and StoC traffic are on different ports on the same NIC?
- How about different ports on different NICs?

Comment: Ask this question on the users dpdk mailing list for quick answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetrical hashing is not directly supported yet by DPDK (as of 16.07). However, there are workarounds discussed in the mailing list [here](http://dpdk.org/ml/archives/dev/2014-December/010310.html). You might also find [this](http://galsagie.github.io/2015/02/26/dpdk-tips-1/) helpful.

Another option is to do the load balancing yourself. For example, you'd have an lcore that pulls on the NIC queues, parse the packet, extract the source/destination ips and ports and calculate a symmetric value (an easy approach would be `(src_port + dst_port + src_ip + dst_ip) % NUM_OF_SOFTWARE_RINGS`

For each lcore worker you'd need to have an rte_ring to connect the load balancing lcore with it. Note that this approach is not nearly as performant as direct RSS.